# why "Between" operator not working with month text in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, operators, between

In my dataset, months are stored in a format as **'June-21', 'Aug-21'** like that.

For a query with `Between`:

```
Select sum(downloads) 
from ratings
where months between 'October-21'and 'December-21';
```

It fetches null values whereas with `IN` operator it gives perfect results.

Query with `IN` Operator:

```
SELECT SUM(downloads) AS total_downloads
FROM ratings 
WHERE months in ('October-21', 'November-21' , 'December-21')
```

Why a query with `between` is not working?

I tried with the `IN` operator, and it worked. But my question is why it is not working with `between`?

[Dataview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtuEJ.png)[error with between operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuTQ4.png)

Comment: BETWEEN means `>=` and `<=`.  'O' >= 'O' and 'O' <= 'D' is an impossible condition.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is your column data type actually a `date` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `BETWEEN a AND B` means *greater or equal to* a *and smaller or equal to* b .

The 'O' of 'October' comes after the 'D' of December, so there is nothing between those two. You are comparing strings, not dates. See also this test:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN 'October-21' < 'December-21' THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS string_comp_test
, CASE 
    WHEN DATE '2021-10-01' < DATE '2021-12-01' THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS date_comp_test
;
```

| string_comp_test | date_comp_test |
| --- | --- |
| FALSE | TRUE |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UcyF6BQP)

Comment: OP says *"In my dataset, months are stored in a format as 'June-21', 'Aug-21' like that"*. So how does your query address that input format (while OP hasn't indicated yet if the column is date type or a string)? :)