# MySQL 5.6 STR-TO-DATE() returns incorrect date (previous month) - bug?

Tags: mysql, string, date

While looking at [a first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76186904/1389394) and its answer I tried to produce a solution.

Because question doesn't mention a schema for table, whether the table data is in date format or just a string; and its answer is only based on a static value in string type but numbers of a usual date format - and not necessary the string input data like format per OP's original question. (at least at the time of this question being posted)

Nonetheless, it intrigued me, what if the table column was a string type with data like 'October-21'. So how to use this as a proper date in a query. When I tried SQLFiddle MySQL Version 5.9. I came across something **peculiar and inconsistent** as follows.

The fiddle can be found [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cf8d6/58)

```
SELECT monthname(STR_TO_DATE('October','%M')), 
STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY'), 
STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY'), 
STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY') + 1, 
STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY') + 1, 
STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY') - 1, 
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY')+1, INTERVAL 1 MONTH),
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY')+1, INTERVAL -1 MONTH),
STR_TO_DATE('Oct','%b'), 
STR_TO_DATE('Sep','%b');
```

Output:

```
monthname(STR_TO_DATE('October','%M'))  
October     

STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY')
2021-09-30  
    
STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY')
2021-10-31  
    
STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY') + 1  
20211001    

STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY') + 1 
20211101        

STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY') - 1 
20211099

STR_TO_DATE('Oct','%b')     
0001-09-30  

STR_TO_DATE('Sep','%b')
0001-08-31

DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
null   

DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY')+1, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
2021-11-01

DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY')+1, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
2021-10-01
```

It also seems return value of `STR_TO_DATE()` is not recognized as a date within `DATE_ADD()` either oppose to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add). Unless +1 input for it is changed to some form of a numeric date. This is rather perplexing.

Has anyone come across why the `STR-TO_DATE` function is producing a month -1 value in this case? Can someone try it in your MySQL installed version?

Comment: Try this fiddle which has much more version options https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: @P.Salmon I had tried it, however it returns null at version 8. For version 5.5 it returns `2021-10-00` and `2021-11-00` for `STR_TO_DATE('October-21','%M-%YY'), 
STR_TO_DATE('November-21','%M-%YY'),` Do you have a proper installed version of MySQL to try this out?

Comment: No thanks - I wouldn't expect useful results when the specifiers used are not those defined https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @P.Salmon you meant `%M`, `%Y` specifiers are not defined in the documentation?

Comment: %Y is but %YY is not..and %y is the specifier for 2 digit year.

Comment: well `%y` still doesn't work - hence the issue

Comment: `str_to_date('November-21','%M-%y') returns null`